# Top margin of bibliography

Tags: margins

How can i reduce the top margin of the bibliography page. I need 1 inch margin at the top but it is 2 inches nw and I don't know how to reduce it.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add some more info on how you are generating your bibliography (BibTeX, biblatex, etc.). A [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) would be the best thing.

Comment: Is it a book? Is bibliography a section or chapter? Without mwe, we won't be able to help, I am afraid.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `geometry` package and write (I suppose you use biblatex, for instance):

```
\newgeometry{top=1in}
\printbibliograpy
\restoregeometry
```

See §7 of the documentation ("Changing layout mid-document").